# How to add space in one row (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart, row, padding

I'm a beginner. I have one row and 2 buttons in it. I want to add space between them, for example padding, margin, container or something. I tried a lot of solutions from other questions, but nothing works for me.

My code:

```
   Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text("Scan"),
        )),
        Expanded(
            child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text("Manually"),
        )),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: You can use a Spacer as well.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FJgd7QN1zI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add padding around the button on which you want to give space

```
Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Scan"),
              )),
              SizedBox(
                width: 100,
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:8.0),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Manually"),
              ),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SizedBox`

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
        child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text("Scan"),
    )), 
    SizedBox(
      width: 100,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text("Manually"),
    )),
  ],
);
```